# My server is sending out emails with spoofed accounts

Tags: spam, windows

I have a windows 2008 R2 server. I am using mailenable proffessional version 7.59.

I noticed on MTA logs that random (non-existing) mail accounts are sending spam email. The emails are from a NULL postoffice, but the domain extensions are correct.

for example. The domain abc.com is configured in mailenable as a post office. and it has only info@abc.com user. However, in the logs I am seeing randomuser_87@abc.com which is sending out emails using smtp-out(2)

I tried everyting to trace these emails to see how they originate but I've had no success. Since it is smtp-out(2), I am assuming they are being sent out by a script on the server. But I might be wrong.

I logged phpmail, I scanned the server for stealth programs, I tried mailenable message trace. But I could nopt find anything.

Has anyone had a similiar experience? Can anyone suggest a way to catch this?

Below is a report I got from /m.usgoabuse.net/ apparently this email has given the spammer away. can anyone tell how this email might have generated?:

```
Received: from [209.143.155.230] by usgo.net
(USGO MTA v5/:PGRlaWRyZS5yaXR0ZXJAcG93ZXJmaW5hbmNldGV4YXMuY29tPjxqa2lzY2hAbW5pbnRlci5uZXQ_)
with SMTP id <20141125073414002607200015> for <jkisch@mninter.net>;
Tue, 25 Nov 2014 07:34:14 -0600 (CST)
(envelope-from deidre.ritter@powerfinancetexas.com, notifiable emailhost server.powerfinancetexas.com)
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
by server.powerfinancetexas.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id A556B39852EE
for <jkisch@mninter.net>; Tue, 25 Nov 2014 07:15:44 -0600 (CST)
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at powerfinancetexas.com
Received: from server.powerfinancetexas.com ([127.0.0.1])
by localhost (server.powerfinancetexas.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
with ESMTP id g8EjglQmmqU3 for <jkisch@mninter.net>;
Tue, 25 Nov 2014 07:15:44 -0600 (CST)
Received: from domaininmyserver.com (ns2.myserver.net [MYSERVERIP])
by server.powerfinancetexas.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 2055639852D5
for <jkisch@mninter.net>; Tue, 25 Nov 2014 07:15:44 -0600 (CST)
Date: Tue, 25 Nov 2014 16:15:32 +0300
To: jkisch@mninter.net
From: WhatsApp Messaging Service <deidre.ritter@powerfinancetexas.com>
Reply-To: WhatsApp Messaging Service <deidre.ritter@powerfinancetexas.com>
Subject: 1 New Voicemail(s)
Message-ID: <92448898bcaeb02b41ce6d783c32762d@domaininmyserver.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.6 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="b1_92448898bcaeb02b41ce6d783c32762d"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

--b1_92448898bcaeb02b41ce6d783c32762d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

WhatsApp





You have a new voicemail!


Details:

Time of Call: Nov-24 2014 06:19:22
Lenth of Call: 50sec




Play


*If you cannot play, move message to the "Inbox" folder.



2014 WhatsApp Inc


--b1_92448898bcaeb02b41ce6d783c32762d
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!doctype html>
<html>
<body style=3D"font-family:Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;">
<div style=3D"width:500px; height:274px;">
<div style=3D"margin:0px; padding:0px; height:85px; background:#27262b;
line-height:75px; font-size:26px; color:#FFFFFF; padding-left:82px; font-=
weight:bold;">
WhatsApp
</div>
<div style=3D"position:ralative;top:100px;background:#34af23; height:8px;=
width:500px;"></div>
<div align=3D"center" style=3D"font-size:18px;color:#5b5f62">
<br>
<br>
You have a new voicemail!
</div>
<div style=3D"padding:20px;">
<font color=3D"#40a9d8"><b>Details:</b></font>
<div style=3D"padding:10px;">
<font color=3D"#00000">Time of Call:</font> Nov-24 2014 06:19:22<br>
<font color=3D"#00000">Lenth of Call:</font> 50sec<br>
<br>
</div>
</div>
<div style=3D"margin:0px; padding:0px; height:180px;" align=3D"center">
<a href=3D"http://phamhongson.net/config.php?w=3DgV82A2+BchVQpCFkL3Jve9P3=
0KzpgPVhGeVFNBdjU9A=3D"=20
style=3D"display:block; width:167px; height:41px; line-height:41px;=20
font-size:26px; color:#ffffff; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;
border-radius:20px; -moz-border-radius:20px; -webkit-border-radius:20px;
background:#67c332; text-decoration:none;">Play</a>
<div style=3D"height:67px; margin:0px; padding:10px;font-size:12px">
<font color=3D"#5b5f62">
*If you cannot play, move message to the "Inbox" folder.
</font>
</div>
<p style=3D"height:30px;margin:0px;padding:10px;color:#FFFFFF;
background:#393e43;font-size:12px">
2014 WhatsApp Inc
</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>



--b1_92448898bcaeb02b41ce6d783c32762d--
```

Comment: I read this several times today, and while I get what you are asking, it would help to have some additional information. But I am not sure what to ask for other than some snippet of any log file and what that log file is. For example, are you absolutely sure that e-mail is being sent out? Or are you getting bounce backs from other SMTP servers? As well, how did you scan the server for stealth programs? What did you use and what settings? Is your server OS fully up to date? Are you using a firewall? I have never heard of Mailenable Proffessional so any answer would likely come from research.

Comment: Below is a log from MXScan. Mxscan is an MTA that scans all emails and processes them. For spam and virus control. :

TimeStamp Identifier Class Type RelatedIP PostOffice Sender Recipient Subject Size(Kb) Time(sec) Score Result Action Scan Test
11/07/14 07:04:35 D69C1E10EBF6441D953F0D3C3F05EC3E_ WHITELISTED SMTP-OUT(2) MY_PRIMARY_IP NULL rebekah_carroll@mydomain.com danielhuntshorse@gmail.co Re:  Wow :) best threesome ever 1 16 0 WHITELISTED Bypassed spam check - IP (MY_PRIMARY_IP) whitelist IP (MY_PRIMARY_IP) Whitelisted

Comment: I have changed the actual IP to "MY_PRIMARY_IP" and the actual domain to "mydomain.com". The domain is a valid domain on my mail server; however the user is spoofed.:

Comment: I used Clam AV to scan the server. The OS is fully upto date. The server is in A data center in Amsterdam (Leaseweb)

Comment: I can see the emails in Mailenable's SMTP OUT que. but it is not possible to trace them with built in email trace. I dont know why, but they seem to go undetected. The MXscan's log suggests that the email originated at the server via script. Because if it was IMAP or SMTP, The Class Type would have been SMTP-OUT(1). I'll post a log of a legitimate SMT transaction below

Comment: TimeStamp Identifier Class Type RelatedIP PostOffice Sender Recipient Subject Size(Kb) Time(sec) Score Result Action Scan Test
11/08/14 11:56:37 1795FE5A39EC4693BA9383FC85ED5215_ WHITELISTED SMTP-OUT(1) 192.168.1.47 mydomain.com info@mydomain.com recepient@gmail.com test email 96 218 0 WHITELISTED Bypassed spam check - Sender whitelist Sender Whitelisted

Comment: I am not sure of what logging levels you have, available, but can you see where clients are connecting in any of your logs? It might be operating as an open relay which may explain a few things. For example, my logs show a connection from ??IP at date and time. It might be that the connections are coming from outside your network.

Comment: Hi, since the RelatedIP is my server's IP, I am assuming that the message is not generating from outside. Server IP's are granted permission to relay.

Comment: You should edit the original question with the logs you have, and use proper formatting there. In comments they are a pain to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't practical to actually do, but here's a strategy that would work:

- Enable process tracking auditing to track processes starting / stopping to the Security Event Log.
- Install Microsoft Network Monitor and capture traffic with a filter for destination TCP port 25.
- Review the captures and correlate with your logs to pinpoint the anomalous email traffic.

Network Monitor will capture the process ID of the program sending the traffic. You can determine, using the Security Event Log, how the process that's sending the offending traffic is getting started.